# How to show and load new data list at the end of old data list with list view in flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, pagination

In my project. There is a **list view** that show data, come from API with pagination.

I used `SmartRefresher` for API pagination and inside of it use `ListView.builder()` to show data list view. Here is my problem. When I fetch next pagination with `SmartRefresher` **(Eg: skipCount is 10)**.Then `ListView.builder()` only show new fresh data and old data `Map` are disappear. What is wanted and expected is when load new data, the new fresh data will showed next to the old data list.(Like in Social media). How can I do that?

**This is  my code implementation of `SmartRefresher()`.**

```
return SmartRefresher(
      enablePullDown: true,
      enablePullUp: true,
      controller: _refreshController,
      header: const WaterDropHeader(),
      footer: CustomFooter(
        builder: (context, LoadStatus? mode) {
          Widget body;
          if (mode == LoadStatus.idle) {
            body = Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: const [
                Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_downward_rounded,
                  size: 15,
                ),
              ],
            );
          } else if (mode == LoadStatus.loading) {
            body = const CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else if (mode == LoadStatus.failed) {
            body = const Text("Load Failed!Click retry!");
          } else if (mode == LoadStatus.canLoading) {
            body = Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: const [
                Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_downward,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 8.0,
                ),
                Text("Load more..."),
              ],
            );
          } else {
            body = const Text("No more Data");
          }
          return SizedBox(
            height: 55.0,
            child: Center(child: body),
          );
        },
      ),
      onRefresh: () {
        widget.notificationBloc.skipCount = 0;
        _refreshController.resetNoData();
        widget.notificationBloc
            .getNotificationList()
            .then((value) => _refreshController.refreshCompleted());
      },
      onLoading: () {
        widget.notificationBloc.skipCount += widget.notificationBloc.limitCount;
        if (widget.notificationBloc.notificationListModel!.total <=
            widget.notificationBloc.skipCount) {
          _refreshController.loadNoData();
        } else {
          widget.notificationBloc
              .getNotificationList(
                  skip: widget.notificationBloc.skipCount,
                  fetchLimitCount: widget.notificationBloc.limitCount)
              .then((value) => _refreshController.loadComplete());
        }
      },
      child: ListView.builder(...),
);
```

**This is my code implementation of fetching Data List with pagination.**

```
final _notificationListController = PublishSubject<MessageState>();

Stream<MessageState> get notificationListStream => _notificationListController.stream;

int skipCount = 0;
int limitCount = 20;

getNotificationList({int skip = 0, int fetchLimitCount = 20}) async {
    try {
      await _notificationRepository
          .getNotificationList(
              notificationListEndPoint: END_POINT_NOTIFICATION_LIST,
              startingNumber: skip,
              fetchCount: fetchLimitCount)
          .then(
        (responseValue) {
          _notificationListController.sink.add(MessageState.loading);
          if (responseValue?.messageState == MessageState.data) {
            notificationListModel = responseValue!.data;
            notificationListData = notificationListModel?.data ?? [];
            _notificationListController.sink.add(MessageState.data);
          } else if (responseValue?.messageState == MessageState.requestError) {
            errorHandlingModel = responseValue?.data;
            _notificationListController.sink.add(MessageState.requestError);
          } else if (responseValue?.messageState == MessageState.serverError) {
            _notificationListController.sink.add(MessageState.serverError);
          }
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      errorMessage = e.toString();
      _notificationListController.sink.add(MessageState.exception);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have implement same Dependency but its working fine may be some method or steps you missed. I will Share my Git code please check pagiation and Swipe refresh both implemented using Getx.

Dependency: **pull_to_refresh: ^2.0.0 or latest**

Example of pagination and SwipeRefresh:
https://github.com/SharmaJatin1997/SwipeRefreshAndPagination

Hope it will helpful for you..

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But I found what I need to do is in BLOC logical operation I need to change from 
`notificationListData = notificationListModel?.data ?? [];` to `notificationListData.addAll(notificationListModel?.data ?? []);`.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I need to do is in BLOC logical operation I need to change from
`notificationListData = notificationListModel?.data ?? [];` to
`notificationListData.addAll(notificationListModel?.data ?? []);`.
Because I realize that I want to show new fetching data will add to the old data in same list.